# Over citation in Springer template with pdflatex

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking, citing

I'm writing a paper for a Springer journal.

So I downloaded the LaTeX template.

http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/LaTeX.zip

The problem is that multiple citations (e.g. `\cite{A,B,C}`) protrude into the right margin, i.e., no line break is added automatically.

```
In previous work [A, 2011, B, 2010, C, 2009]
, suggests
```

But I want to write it like this.

```
In previous work [A, 2011, B, 2010,
C, 2009], suggests
```

I use `spbasic` and `apalike`, but the problem is not fixed.

```
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

Is there any good bibliography style for writing a Springer journal paper?

Or how can I solve this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also note that you should use exactly one `\bibliographystyle` command.

Comment: Thanks to edting the question and leaving a comment. There is a rule to ask question in TeX.sx. I don't know it. I should do it later. Thanks again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the journal's problem, not yours - the manuscript you send in for refereeing is in effect a draft, and it is the journal that will turn this into the proofs that are published.  The editors usually like it if you use the official style files - I doubt any benefit from a more attractive review manuscript will outweigh the slight lack of professionalism that comes with sending a manuscript that does not use the correct style files.  I recommend you do not worry about the citation protrusion.

Incidentally, you should not treat the part of citations within brackets as nouns: the excerpt you have should better be `Previous work [A, 2011, B, 2010, C, 2009] suggests...` or `Previous work suggests ... [A, 2011, B, 2010, C, 2009]`, with the citation at the end of the sentence.

Comment: Thanks to answering my question and suggesting good way to write the paper. In fact, it is first time to write and submit the paper to Springer journal. So I don't know about the process in more detail. Thanks again!

Answer (score 13):

First, use only one bibliography style in your document. Here, I would suggest spbasic, as you would like to publish at Springer.

The `spbasic` style uses author-year citations, and formats `bibitem`s accordingly. Therefore, you should use the `natbib` option of the `svjour3` document class. This holds also for the `apalike` style.

```
\documentclass[smalcondensed,draft,natbib]{svjour3}

\begin{document}

Some leading text to push the citations~\cite{StGu92,GhJaEn20,MeGa05,Ma00,MuBeBoRo99,BaNi94,Ca04}.

% \bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Without the `natbib` option:
[image: without natbib option]

With the `natbib` option:
[image: with natbib option]

Comment: Thanks, works for me (Corneli, 2015)!  Migrating from APA cite, I made use of these command aliases:  `\let\oldcite\cite`
`\let\cite\citep`
`\let\citeA\oldcite`
`\let\citeNP\oldcite`
`\let\citeyear\citeyearpar`  ... That allows me to compile the old document without changing the body.